# How to explode a row into multiple rows without using data frames?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have created dataframes for exploding a row into multiple rows based on delimiter. I have used explode function for same. Would like to know if i can by pass the use of dataframe here and use only SparkSQL to perform this operation.

Example there is Strtok function in teradata to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer**: There is no built-in function in SQL that helps you efficiently breaking a row to multiple rows based on (string value and delimiters), as compared to what `flatMap()` or `explode()` in ([Dataset API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)) can achieve.

And simply it is because in Dataframe you can manipulate `Rows` programmatically in much higher level and granularity than Spark SQL.

**Note:** `Dataset.explode()` is deprecated starting from ([Spark 2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset))

> explode() Deprecated: (Since version 2.0.0) use flatMap() or select() with
>   functions.explode() instead

Here are two examples for both methods recommended from the previous quote.

**Examples**

```
// Loading testing data
val mockedData = sc.parallelize(Seq("hello, world", "foo, bar")).toDF
+------------+
|       value|
+------------+
|hello, world|
|    foo, bar|
+------------+
```

**Option 1 - flatMap()**

Breaking rows into multiples using `flatMap()`

```
scala> mockedData.flatMap( r => r.getString(0).split(",")).show
+------+
| value|
+------+
| hello|
| world|
|   foo|
|   bar|
+------+
```

**Option 2 - functions.explode()**

Replacing value column with a new set of `Rows` generated by `explode()`, which is deprecated in favor of using `flatMap()`

```
scala> mockedData.withColumn("value", explode(split($"value", "[,]"))).show
+------+
| value|
+------+
| hello|
| world|
|   foo|
|   bar|
+------+
```

**Switching to Spark SQL API:**

If you want to use sqlContext, and start querying data through SQL, now you can create a temporary view from the resulted Dataset:

```
scala> val resultedDf = mockedData.flatMap( r => r.getString(0).split(","))
resultedDf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> resultedDf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

scala> spark.sql("select * from temp").show
+------+
| value|
+------+
| hello|
| world|
|   foo|
|   bar|
+------+
```

I hope this answers your question.